# Android: How to set tag to fragments in FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here's the inner class that contains fragments and changes fragment views on swipe. This class is defined in an `Activity`.

```
private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int count;

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int count) {
        super(fm);
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                return new FriendsListFragment();

            case 1:
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(Keys.TAG, ChatListFragment.class.getSimpleName());
                ChatListFragment chatListFragment = new ChatListFragment();
                chatListFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                return chatListFragment;

            case 2:
                return new MoreFragment();

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Here I would like to add a code that sets tags to each fragment, so that I can recognize which fragment I'm at.

I searched quite much, and I haven't found a proper answer for this question, so please help.

Comment: you can also detect which fragment you are in using viewpager pagechange listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `setPrimaryItem` method of your `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

```
 private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        protected int currentPosition = -1;
        protected Fragment currentFragment;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           // ....
        }

        @Override
        public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
            this.currentPosition = position;
            if (object instanceof Fragment) {
                this.currentFragment = (Fragment) object;
            }
        }

        public int getCurrentPosition() {
            return currentPosition;
        }

        public Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
            return currentFragment;
        }
    }
```

Just use getCurrentPosition or getCurrentFragment methods to get information about current Fragment.